# How to get realtime Changes in firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I Have a chat list(RecyclerView) which I retrieve from Firestore which I sort with respect to the timestamp. The problem which occurs is The list get updated only when the activity is created Else it sits idle.

I have tried Running fetching code in the Onresume as well.But it just creates another set of same items.

```
firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

            Query secondquery = firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(currentUser).collection("Chat").orderBy("timestamp",Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

            secondquery.addSnapshotListener((MainActivity.this), new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                    for (DocumentChange doc : documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                        if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {

                            String UserId=doc.getDocument().getId();

                            ChatList chatList = doc.getDocument().toObject(ChatList.class).withId(UserId);
                            chatLists.add(chatList);
                            chatListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }



                }
            });
```

I expect it to get updated as soon as the new document is added. But it remains idle until I reopen the activity

Comment: In firebase you do not have to write code onresume. You can write on onCreate method and just change data in firebase or firestore it will be change atuomatically.

Comment: What do you mean through "it sits idle"?

Comment: The `onEvent` of your listener should fire whenever data in the query changes. You might want to set a breakpoint in that method and run in the debugger to see if it triggers. And if it does, to see what type of data you're getting.